# jquery как обратиться к this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here code:

```
<form onsubmit="func(this); return false">
<div class="class"></div>
</form>
```

Как можно в функции func, обратиться к дочернему классу class? Я знаю про способ find, $(elem).find('.class')... но хотелось бы узнать как можно сделать это без файнда.

То есть что-то на подобии

```
function func(elem) {
$(elem .class)...
}
```

Comment: `elem.querySelector('.class')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А чем вам `find()` не угодил? Хороший метод, работает быстро... Можно и без него, есть такой синтаксис:

```
$('child_selector', elem);
```

Comment: Тем что предоставленный вами метод короче.